# Zariski closure of product is product of Zariski closures

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, zariski-topology

Let $X \subseteq \mathbb{A}^{n}$, $Y \subseteq \mathbb{A}^{m}$, where $\mathbb{A}^{n}$ is the affine $n$-space with Zariski topology.

Let $\overline{X}$, $\overline{Y}$ and $\overline{X \times Y}$ be the Zariski closures of $X$, $Y$ and $X \times Y$ (i.e. $\overline{X}$ is the smallest algebraic set in $\mathbb{A}^{n}$ containing $X$, $\overline{Y}$ is the smallest algebraic set in $\mathbb{A}^{m}$ containing $Y$, and $\overline{X \times Y}$ is the smallest algebraic set in $\mathbb{A}^{n+m}$ containing $X \times Y$).

I am asked to show that $$\overline{X \times Y} = \overline{X} \times \overline{Y}$$

I have already shown that $\overline{X} \times \overline{Y}$ is an algebraic set in $\mathbb{A}^{n+m}$, which immediately implies $$\overline{X \times Y} \subseteq \overline{X} \times \overline{Y}$$

However, I don't know how to show that $\overline{X \times Y} \supseteq \overline{X} \times \overline{Y}$. Any help/hints would be appreciated.

Comment: This is in fact true for any general topology. You can use the fact: $x \in \overline{A}$ iff any open nbd of $x$ intersects non-trivially with $A$.

Comment: @thedilated I know it's true if you're using the product topology on $\mathbb{A}^{n} \times \mathbb{A}^{m}$. However, the Zariski topology on $\mathbb{A}^{n+m}$ is not the same as the product topology on $\mathbb{A}^{n} \times \mathbb{A}^{m}$. As far as I can tell, the result you mention does not apply in this case. This question is asking to show that the smallest algebraic set in $\mathbb{A}^{n+m}$ containing $X \times Y$ is $\overline{X} \times \overline{Y}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show $\overline{X}\times\overline{Y}\subseteq \overline{X\times Y},$ you can show that every polynomial that vanishes on $X\times Y$ must vanish on $\overline{X}\times\overline{Y}.$

So, consider a polynomial $r(X,Y)$ that vanishes on $X\times Y.$
For each $x\in X$ the polynomial $f(Y)=r(x,Y)$ vanishes on $Y,$ so must vanish on $\overline{Y}.$ So $r$ vanishes on $X\times \overline{Y}.$
For each $y\in \overline{Y},$ the polynomial $f(X)=r(X,y)$ vanishes on $X,$ so must vanish on $\overline{X}.$ So $r$ vanishes on $\overline{X}\times\overline{Y}.$